# How to plot stacked bars using hist()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I  trying to plot a stacked bar chart as part of a `plt.subplots`.
I currently have:

```
bin_n=100
df_name['column_name'].hist(bins=bin_n, ax=axs[0,1])
```

and I would like to add a categorical (string) column in the game.

My data set is like:

```
string_column  column_name
'A'                4.3
'A'                4
'B'                4.8
'B'                5
'B'                6.8
```

I've read a lot of examples of stacked bars but all of them are using arrays.
So my questions are:

Do I need to transform my dataset?
Can I apply stacked bars using hist() as above? If yes, how exactly?

Comment: What's your expected outcome? Do you want to stack per histogram or per category?

Comment: I would like stack per category.

Answer (score -1):

```
df_name.pivot(index='column1', columns='string_column', values='column_name') \
    .plot(kind='hist', stacked=True)
```

Comment: Your answer may be the right solution, but Please add some explanation for the current and future developers facing similar questions. Remember, stackoverflow is a community place for answers to questions with explanation.